# Estimating Power and Energy Consumption of a Spiking Neural Network

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, cpu, cpu-usage

I have a traditional Convolutional Neural Network (CNN), and I've converted that to a Spiking CNN (S-CNN). I wanted to compare them on the basis of power and energy consumption. By using a different software (Nengo), I got the energy consumption of the CNN on CPU, but for the spiking network, I got the energy consumption (J per inference) on Neuromorphic Hardware (Loihi). However, I want to obtain the **energy consumption of the Spiking Network on CPU as well**. I have the following parameters known exactly:

- CNN energy consumption(CPU): 6.94 mJ/inference, CNN runtime(CPU): **16
  ms**, CNN operations: **0.85*10^6 MACs** (Multiply and Accumulate
  Operations).
- S-CNN runtime(CPU): **30 ms**, S-CNN operations: **1.6*10^6 ACCs**
  (Only    Accumulate Operations).

Is there a way to estimate the energy consumption of the S-CNN on CPU using these parameters? I remember reading somewhere (Can't find the source now) that Multiply and Accumulate and Accumulate operations have the same power consumption. So, the S-CNN will consume (1.6/0.85)*(30/16) ~ 3.5 times more energy on CPU.

Is there any other way to do this estimation? A crude estimation will also do.

Comment: Yes, MAC and MUL are about the same hardware complexity and should be very similar energy per operation.  But you said your second S-CNN only uses accumulate, like integer or FP add operations.  Those are cheaper for energy; integer add is very cheap.  FP add costs less energy than FP mul, despite having similar latency on modern hardware.  Many fewer transistors need to switch every cycle since you don't have many partial products being added.  You do still need to shift based on exponents to align the mantissa, then add, then scan for the most significant bit and generate a result exponent.